# Importing Dates into Access 2013

Tags: excel, csv, ms-access

What types of date values will access recognize when you are importing? I have a csv file that has a date field that Excel recognizes but Access does not (data conversion error).

Answer (score 0):

When you are importing dates, the import form has a section which lets you define what format your dates are in. There is a chance your regional settings are also in play, so make sure the form matches your data. Remember that UK uses dd/mm/yyyy by default and the USA uses mm/dd/yyyy format.